# Tesseract Development

Tags: visual-c++

I am quite new into application development.

Just wanted to ask you guys, How do I implement the source code from Tesseract inside Visual Studio that I could compile and run? What are steps I have to do to get it running? I can't seem to find the full project file for it. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the instruction for building on Windows from this page?

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/Compiling

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

While a go I was in the same situation, Google Code was shutting down and the official Github Tesseract implementation for Visual Studio was really buggy, old and didn't compile.

This repository with a ready to go VS 3.02 tesseract implementation with Leptonica helped me:

https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-vs2012

It has a documentation how to run it. But basically you have to open it with VS and run it. It will create the dll and libraries required to use Tesseract in a VS Project and the binaries ready to go using Command Lines.

If you need the documentation for Tesseract 3.02 or higher you can find it here:

http://tesseract-ocr.github.io/modules.html

The oficial forum is in google groups there you will find some examples:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tesseract-ocr

Comment: Greetings. Please check out [Take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)

Comment: He asked how to compile/run Tesseract inside Visual Studio. I provided an  updated implementation of Tesseract using Visual Studio, I don't see the issue here.

Comment: I don't know. Did you read the link I provided? Link-only answers *often* get deleted. Something to think about.

Comment: Fixed  with a better explanation ;)